# Global method without modification of class

Tags: ruby

I have many class with many objects and I would like to apply a method on these objects (of different unrelated classes)

Example:

```
pig = animal.new
pig.name = "lulu"
human = person.new
human.firstname = "John"  #There isn't method called "name".

def seeName
 puts self.name if (self.name?)
 puts self.firstname if (self.firstname?)
end

pig.seeName
human.seeName
```

It's just an example...
I think that it's not possible but I'm looking for a way to do this without modify any existing classes.

Thank you.

Comment: is `name?` and `firstname?` you defined in your many different classes ? It is need to know before thinking about the method `see_name` ..

Answer (score 5):

You can define the method inside a `module`, and then include it at runtime to the needed classes

```
pig = Animal.new
pig.name = "lulu"
human = Person.new
human.firstname = "John" 

module SeeName
  def see_name
    puts self.name if (self.name?)
    puts self.firstname if (self.firstname?)
  end
end

Person.class_eval { include SeeName }
Animal.class_eval { include SeeName }

pig.see_name # => "lulu"
human.see_name # => "John"
```

(provided, of course that both Person and Animal support `name`, `name?`, `firstname` and `firstname?`)

Comment: Thank you !
Does exist a solution to apply `class_eval` to every classes in a loaded file ?

Comment: are they all under the same namespace (module)?

Comment: Not at all. But it's maybe possible to include `load('classes_types.rb')` into a module.

Comment: I guess you jump through a few hoops to find out which classes were declared in some file, but I think the simplest will be to maintain the list elsewhere, and then do something like `[Person, Animal, ...].each { |c| c.class_eval { include SeeName } }`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do:

```
def see_name(object)
  return object.name if object.respond_to? :name
  object.firstname if object.respond_to :firstname
end

see_name(pig)    #=> "lulu"
see_name(human)  #=> "John"
```

However this is not a proper way to do things in OOP. Every time you face problems like this it means your object design is going the wrong way and needs to be revisited.

Comment: Yes, I thought it just after my post ! Thank :)

Answer (score -1):

A coworker told me that there is another way :

```
class Object
  def seeName
    puts self.name if (self.name?)
    puts self.firstname if (self.firstname?)
  end
end

pig.seeName
human.seeName
```

Until now it works very well.

Comment: I don't think it is advisable to change the `Object` class for something so application-specific - it is too disruptive - now you have defined `'123'.seeName` as well...

Comment: @Uri Agassi : Oh yes, I didn't think that but I'll never use seeName method with a object which doesn't support this.
I'll try your solution!

Comment: Just because you wouldn't doesn't mean that some unwary maintainer won't.